# Facebook landing page not working - did they change something

Tags: facebook, default

Built a pretty cool reveal application.  And i set the application tab as my Default Landing Tab.  It seems like Facebook is ignoring that and using my wall as the default page.  I know for a fact that this was working and it just stopped recently...  Did Facebook make a change again?  Is this a bug?

the page is

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Web-Inspired-Inc/195395460536233?sk=app_281819945171158

Answer (score 2):

If you are the page admin or if you have already liked the page, it will always default to the Wall.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're an admin. You can be an admin and not like the page.

Comment: Actually, if you're the admin you will always default to the Wall.

Answer (score 1):

Try "unliking" your page. The default tab is only the default for people who haven't liked you.

Edit: Unliking the page won't have any effect if you're an admin. I have a 'fake' FB account that I use to test things in my apps. Not strictly compliant with their TOS, probably, but it's the best way I know of to really see how normal users see your apps and pages.